# Puppeteer: How to submit a form?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

Using [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer), how could you programmatically submit a form? So far I've been able to do this using `page.click('.input[type="submit"]')` if the form actually includes a submit input. But for forms that don't include a submit input, focusing on the form text input element and using `page.press('Enter')` doesn't seem to actually cause the form to submit:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/', {waitUntil: 'load'});
    console.log(page.url());

    // Type our query into the search bar
    await page.focus('.js-search-field');
    await page.type('puppeteer');

    // Submit form
    await page.press('Enter');

    // Wait for search results page to load
    await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'load'});


    console.log('FOUND!', page.url());

    // Extract the results from the page
    const links = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const anchors = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.result-link a'));
      return anchors.map(anchor => anchor.textContent);
    });
    console.log(links.join('\n'));
    browser.close();

})();
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If you are attempting to fill out and submit a **login form**, you can use the following:

```
await page.goto('https://www.example.com/login');

await page.type('#username', 'username');
await page.type('#password', 'password');

await page.click('#submit');

await page.waitForNavigation();

console.log('New Page URL:', page.url());
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if the inputs already have content like in the case of updating a form, this method will prepend the data already in the input field.

Comment: @mckenna "Another interesting solution is to click the target field 3 times so that the browser would select all the text in it and then you could just type what you want:" `await input.click({ clickCount: 3 })` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52633235/556169

Answer (score 46):

Try this

```
const form = await page.$('form-selector');
await form.evaluate(form => form.submit());
```

---

For v0.11.0 and laters:

```
await page.$eval('form-selector', form => form.submit());
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like the issue was not using `.evaluate()` on the form element - didn't know you could do that.

Comment: @NamMaiAnh i am getting TypeError: form.evaluate is not a function

Comment: @redochka May you show me the code? Have you determined if `form` was `null` or not?

Comment: @NamMaiAnh 'ElementHandle' do not have the 'evaluate' method.

Comment: @Abdel I have updated the answer for v0.11.0 and laters. Thank you!

Comment: `await page.evaluate(form => form.submit(), form);` is the correct syntax.

Comment: Also, it fails when you use just `await page.type('puppeteer');` but add this to the selection `await page.type('.js-search-field', 'puppeteer');`

Answer (score 2):

I was scraping a SPA, and I had to use `waitForNetworkIdle` since the form submit was not triggering a page navigation event. Instead it submitted data to the server, and updated the DOM of the page which was already loaded.

```
const [response] = await Promise.all([        
    page.waitForNetworkIdle(),
    page.click('#form-submit-button'),
]);
```

### When to use `waitForNetworkIdle`

I suspect that if you open a normal web browser, submit the form, and look to see if the page URL has changed or not. If it has not changed, you should use  `waitForNetworkIdle`.

Also, take this advice with a grain of salt, I've only been using puppeteer for an hour.

Comment: This comment marks the date of my first up-vote on this answer. I am so glad I was able to help solve your problem.