# puppeteer - how to submit form

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

How do I submit the form?
I have a simple search bar and a search button. The following enters the search string, but the click event is not fired. When headless is set to false and I manully click enter in the serachfield, the search is working. How to submit the button?

```
  const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('http://localhost:3000', {waitUntil: 'networkidle'});

await page.focus('#search');

// Type our query into the search bar
await page.type('michael');

// Submit form
await page.press('Enter');

await page.screenshot({path: './screenshots/search3.png'});

browser.close();
})();
```

My searchbar

```
search(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
this.props.onClick(this.props.value);}

render() {
return (<form className="form-inline" id="search-form" onSubmit
{this.search}>
  <div className="form-group">
    <input
      type="text"
      className="form-control"
      id="search"
      value={this.props.value}
      placeholder={this.props.placeHolder}
      onChange={this.props.onChange}
    />

    <button primary type="submit" >
      {this.props.buttonText}
    </button>
  </div>
</form>);
}
```

**UPDATE**

**This is not working:**

```
const searchForm = await page.$('#search-form'); 
await searchForm.evaluate(searchForm => searchForm.submit());
```

It does a postback and the text in the form was cleared, even though it should trigger the function with preventDefault.

So the issue seems to be this line of code await

```
searchForm.evaluate(searchForm => searchForm.submit());
```

**This is working:**

I changed the code to:

```
await page.click('#search-button'); 
await page.waitForNavigation();
```

Comment: what the screenshot look's like, if the problem not solved yet. Please consider attaching it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved it by using this instead of submitting the form:

```
await page.click('#search-button'); 
await page.waitForNavigation();
```

Comment: When clicking a button gives validation errors, how to go back to previous page?

Answer (score 5):

You can submit the form by sending:
`await page.click("button[type=submit]");`

> Found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46965168/8839237

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your search bar has "search" as its ID,

Basically you need to use the selector expression to get a handle to your search bar and then using the `evaluate` function you can do the form submission,

You need to have the below snippet to submit your form,

```
const searchForm = await page.$('#search');
await searchForm.evaluate(searchForm => searchForm.submit());
```

Hope this helps

Comment: well now the form is triggered, but my onSubmit function is not used. I have added the form code to the question.

When the form is submitted, the search string disappears and my url turns into 
`localhost:3000/?`. 

When doing it manually the searchString is stored in the searchfield and the url turns into 
`localhost:3000/?searchString=michael`

Comment: @Kristoffer Did you try adding my suggestions?.. (or) your code has started working now?

Comment: I added your suggestions, and now puppeteer seems to run (it doesn't break), but I don't get the expected output. It doesn't seem like the right onSubmit function is triggered.

Comment: @Kristoffer Can you please remove your `onSubmit` handler and check if it is running as expected?

Comment: without my onSubmit handler 
`<form className="form-inline" id="search-form">` it still empties the search input box.
If I do it manually I don't get any search result due to a missing onSubmit handler.

Comment: @Kristoffer Please change your `<form...` declaration as `<form className="form-inline" id="search-form" action="" method="GET">` and see if it is working.

Comment: Same result with `<form className="form-inline" id="search-form" action="" method="GET">` But then it also do a postbak, because I'm missing e.preventDefault().
It's the same result with `<form className="form-inline" id="search-form" action="" method="GET" onSubmit={this.search}>`

Comment: If I change it to do the same search on stackoverflow (changing the id's/classnames) the search is working. So it's something with my form/setup?

Comment: This is working:
`await page.click('#search-button');
  await page.waitForNavigation();`

This is not working:
`const searchForm = await page.$('#search-form');
  await searchForm.evaluate(searchForm => searchForm.submit());`

So the issue seems to be this line of code
`await searchForm.evaluate(searchForm => searchForm.submit());`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154403/discussion-between-david-r-and-kristoffer).

Comment: Great! Please update your post with what you've debugged, Hope it will definitely help someone!

Answer (score 0):

**first follow this link**

[puppeteer-how-to-submit-a-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45778181/puppeteer-how-to-submit-a-form?rq=1)

**your question**

when you press an enter than screenshot it, this is the questions.

```
// this code just await press event finished, but not form submitted finished,
//in this way, you can not screenshot form submit finished status
await page.press('Enter'); 
await page.screenshot({path: './screenshots/search3.png'});
// form submitting ...
```

This is why your code not works.

hopes to help you

Comment: The issue was not the screenshot, but submitting the form. If I disabled the screenshot it still didn't submit the form correct.

I tried to run it without headless so I could see that the form was not submitted properly even after the screenshot.