# Puppeteer wait page load after form submit

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I submit a form using the following code and i want Puppeteer to wait page load after form submit.

```
await page.click("button[type=submit]");

//how to wait until the new page loads before taking screenshot?
// i don't want this:
// await page.waitFor(1*1000);  //← unwanted workaround
await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
```

How to wait for page load with puppeteer?

Answer (score 130):

You can wait for navigation asynchronously to avoid getting `null` on redirection,

```js
await Promise.all([
    page.click('button[type=submit]'),
    page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle2'})
]);
```

This will help you if the page.click already triggers a navigation.

Comment: this is a race condition. 
 https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1412#issuecomment-345294748   shuold use this instead:`let nav = page.waitForNavigation();
 await page.click("button[type=submit]");
 await nav;`  https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1412#issuecomment-345294748

Comment: @dQw4w9WyXcQ Both patterns are the same, neither is a race condition.

Answer (score 76):

```
await page.waitForNavigation();
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and `await Promise.all([page.click..., page.waitForNavigation...]);` ?

Comment: @NathanGoings Here it is only one promise to resolve while promise.all will resolve multiple promises (not necessarily in sequence)

Answer (score 46):

According to the [Official Documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions), you should use:

> #### page.waitForNavigation(options)
>
> - `options` <[Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)> Navigation parameters which might have the following properties:
>
>   - `timeout` <[number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type)> Maximum navigation time in milliseconds, defaults to 30 seconds, pass `0` to disable timeout. The default value can be changed by using the [page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(timeout)](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetdefaultnavigationtimeouttimeout) method.
>   - `waitUntil` <[string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#String_type)|[Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)<[string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#String_type)>> When to consider navigation succeeded, defaults to `load`. Given an array of event strings, navigation is considered to be successful after all events have been fired. Events can be either:
>
>     - `load` - consider navigation to be finished when the `load` event is fired.
>     - `domcontentloaded` - consider navigation to be finished when the `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired.
>     - `networkidle0` - consider navigation to be finished when there are no more than 0 network connections for at least `500` ms.
>     - `networkidle2` - consider navigation to be finished when there are no more than 2 network connections for at least `500` ms.
> - returns: <[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)<[?Response]>> Promise which resolves to the main resource response. In case of multiple redirects, the navigation will resolve with the response of the last redirect. In case of navigation to a different anchor or navigation due to History API usage, the navigation will resolve with `null`.

#### Readability:

You can use [`page.waitForNavigation()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions) to wait for a page to navigate:

```
await page.waitForNavigation();
```

#### Performance:

But since `page.waitForNavigation()` is a shortcut for `page.mainFrame().waitForNavigation()`, we can use the following for a minor performance enhancement:

```
await page._frameManager._mainFrame.waitForNavigation();
```

Comment: I'm trying to wait for an image in a popover to load. Is it possible to just pause for 10 seconds? None of these values work for me.

Comment: The performance hint is a premature optimization and won't have any practical on the real-world performances. Plus it's more likely to break after an upgrade of puppeteer as it's using internal API

Answer (score 30):

Sometimes even using `await page.waitForNavigation()` will still result in a `Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation.`

In my case, it was because the page was redirecting multiple times. The [API](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions) says the default `waitUntil` option is `Load`—this required me to wait for navigation each redirect (3 times).

Using only a single instance of [`page.waitForNavigation`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions) with the `waitUntil` option `networkidle2` worked well in my case:

```js
await button.click();

await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
```

Finally, the API suggests using a `Promise.All` to prevent a race condition.  *I haven't needed this but provide it for completeness*:

```js
await Promise.all([button.click(), page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil:'networkidle2'})])
```

If all else fails, you can use [`page.waitForSelector`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options) as recommended on a [Puppeteer github issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3323)—or in my case, [`page.waitForXPath()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforxpathxpath-options)

Comment: I had a redirect that lasted so long that only `networkidle0` worked properly.

Comment: Over a year later I'm coming back to say, `networkidle0` can mysteriously fail (heartbeats, webpack hmr, etc.)  In my current script I'm using `page.waitForSelector`

Comment: You can combine multiple options and wrap each of them in a `try catch` block to ensure you've exhausted your options before calling it quits and logging an error.

Answer (score 14):

i suggest to wrap page.to in a wrapper and wait for everything loaded

this is my wrapper

```
loadUrl: async function (page, url) {
    try {
        await page.goto(url, {
            timeout: 20000,
            waitUntil: ['load', 'domcontentloaded', 'networkidle0', 'networkidle2']
        })
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error("url " + url + " url not loaded -> " + error)
    }
}
```

now you can use this with

```
await loadUrl(page, "https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: Isn't waiting for `networkidle0` superseded by waiting for `networkidle2`?

Answer (score 12):

I know it is bit late to answer this. It may be helpful for those who are getting below exception while doing **waitForNavigation**.

> (node:14531) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError:
>   Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded
>       at Promise.then (/home/user/nodejs/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/LifecycleWatcher.js:142:21)
>       at    -- ASYNC --
>       at Frame. (/home/user/nodejs/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
>       at Page.waitForNavigation (/home/user/nodejs/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:649:49)
>       at Page. (/home/user/nodejs/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:112:23)
>       at /home/user/nodejs/user/puppeteer/example7.js:14:12
>       at

The correct code that worked for me is as below.

```
await page.click('button[id=start]', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
```

Similarly if you are going to a new page, code should be like

```
await page.goto('here goes url', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
```

Answer (score 7):

None of the above answers solved my issue. Sometimes waitForNavigation just timeout. I came up with other solution using the waitForFunction, checking if document is in ready state.

```
await page.waitForFunction(() => document.readyState === "complete");
```

Answer (score 5):

```
await Promise.all([
      page.click(selectors.submit),
      page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }),
]);
```

This would be the first priority to use as it waits for all network to complete and assumes it is done when you don't have more than 0 network call for 500ms.

you can also use

```
await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'load' })
```

or else, you can use

```
await page.waitForResponse(response => response.ok())
```

this function can also be used in various places as it only allows to proceed further when all the calls are a success that is when all the response status is ok i.e (200-299)

Comment: `waitUntil: 'load'`. Only lowercase is valid. ref: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions

Answer (score 2):

### This works for me

> Puppeteer version: 19.2.2

```
page.click(".clickable-selector");
await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "load" });
```

Note:
If you do this inside a loop. ( scrapping page-1, click to page-2, scrapping page-2 and so on... )

```
await page.waitForSelector(".clickable-selector", { visible: true });
```

Wait for this clickable selector before doing any other scrapping on the page.

Comment: `page.click(".clickable-selector");` should be awaited, and the `waitForNavigation` should be set before. The [correct pattern is shown elsewhere on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46965168/6243352).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
await Promise.all([
    page.goto(URL),
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }),
]);
console.log('page loaded')
```

For some reason I was not able to click button (Handled an event, not in form)

```
<button onclick="someFunction();" class="button button2">Submit</button>
```

The problem was that page was rendered on server side. Thus the button didn't existed whenever I waited for input field `await page.waitForSelector('button.button2')`

The solution was to bind `page.goto(URL)` and `page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })` in `Promise`

```
await Promise.all([
    page.goto(URL),
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }),
]);
console.log('page loaded')

await page.waitForSelector('button.button2')
console.log('button is here');
```

Comment: Im late on this, but how does this work reliably? page.goto by default does a waitUntil, then your second waitForNavigation is going to wait for a navigation that will never happen because the first one responds?

Answer (score 1):

If submitting the form opens some other page, then you may just want to wait for a selector in that page. I have often had issues using `page.waitForNavigation()` since it's options don't really ensure we have effectively navigated to another page.

```
// login page
page.click("#login");
// homepage, after login
page.waitForSelector("#home", {visible: true}); // page.waitForXpath()
```

Of you course you can increase the wait time for the selector.

Comment: These promises must be awaited. The [correct pattern is shown elsewhere on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46965168/6243352).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a scenario, where there was the classic POST-303-GET and an `input[type=submit]` was involved. It seems that in this case, the `click` of the button won't resolve until after the associated form's submission and redirection, so the solution was to remove the `waitForNavigation`, because it was executed after the redirection and thus was timing out.

Answer (score -1):

Please try

```
await page.waitForNavigation()
```

or

```
await page.waitForSelector("#indecator_of_any_element_of_you_are_waiting_for")
```

Answer (score -1):

I achieved the best results for a similar use case with the following:

```
await page.waitForSelector("button[type=submit]");

await page.click("button[type=submit]", {
      waitUntil: "networkidle2",
});

await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
```

Basically, the use case differs for every website configuration. I highly recommend to create a command based function like i did for my project:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

// Sample command set
const commands = [
{ id: 1, type: 'goto', target: '/dummy-product/' },
{ id: 2, type: 'goto', target: '/about-page' },
{ id: 4, type: 'goto', target: '/test-page' }, //size text label
];

const bot = async (url, commands) => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(url);

const statuses = [];

for (let command of commands) {
    let status = { id: command.id, status: 'failed' };

    try {
        switch (command.type) {
            case 'click':
                await page.waitForSelector(command.target);
                await page.click(command.target, {
                    waitUntil: "networkidle2",
                  });
                if(command.form){
                    await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
                }
                status.status = 'success';
                status.message = `${command.type}: ${command.target}`;
                break;
            case 'goto':
                await page.goto(url + command.target, {
                    waitUntil: "networkidle2",
                  });
                await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
                status.status = 'success';
                status.message = `${command.type}: ${command.target}`;
                break;
            case 'select':
                await page.waitForSelector(command.target);
                await page.focus(command.target, {delay: 1000});
                await page.select(command.target, command.value);
                status.status = 'success';
                status.message = `${command.type}: ${command.target}`;
                break;
            case 'input':
                await page.waitForSelector(command.target);
                await page.focus(command.target);
                await page.keyboard.type(command.value);
                status.status = 'success';
                status.message = `${command.type}: ${command.target}`;
                break;
            // You can add more command types here.
            default:
                console.log(`Unknown command type: ${command.type}`);
                status.status = 'failed';
                status.message = 'Unknown command type';
                break;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        status.status = `failed`;
        status.message = error.message;
    }

    statuses.push(status);
}

await browser.close();

return statuses;

}

bot('https://example.com/', commands)
.then(statuses => console.log(statuses))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'waitUntil' does not exist in type 'Readonly<ClickOptions>'.