# How to wait for jquery to be loaded after await page.addScriptTag({url: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'}) in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, puppeteer

**CODE:**

```
await page.addScriptTag({url: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'});
```

---

**PROBLEM**:

I add jquery to the page with the line above so that I can use it to select elements in Puppeteer. Everything works fine for a few pages, until the error "$ is not defined" appears.

**Edit**: To be clear, the first url is loaded and then puppeteer navigates by clicking the "next" button to go to the next page, thus opening a new page at a new url.

---

**WHAT I TRIED:**

I have tried the following:

1)

```
 await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(fs.readFileSync('./public/js/jquery.js', 'utf8'));
```

2)

```
page.on('framenavigated', async frame => {
                    if (frame !== page.mainFrame()) { return; } 
                    else {
                        await page.addScriptTag({path: './public/js/jquery.js'});
                    }
            })
```

3)

```
 await page.addScriptTag({url: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'});
```

Nothing works. What would you suggest ?

Comment: Maybe the url after "a few pages" overwrites the jQuery? Is it the same url as the first url?

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher No, it's a different url every time a page is changed. What is strange is that the error only appears after a random number of pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use waitForFunction,

```
await page.addScriptTag({url: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'});
await page.waitForFunction(() => window.jQuery);
```

It will wait until the windows has a jQuery variable and resolve when it does.

Comment: Hi @Abu. The page.addScriptTag already waits for the "load" event of the script. This means that the jquery is already on window when the first line is done. Probably TheProgrammer has another problem, but your answer is not correct.

Comment: @Icrespilho It actually ended up solving my issue by adding it to the beginning of the loop I have to go through all the pages I am interested in (by loading the initial url and then clicking the "Next" button). Most likely my issue was that on some iteration of the loop, we would already reach the part where Jquery is used before the script actually loaded for the new page ? Or would addscriptTag already by default execute for all new pages despite being used on the page of only the initial url ? Regardless, it's working now :)

Comment: As a side not, it seemed I had already fixed the issue by using `waitForNavigation` (which amusingly enough was also a solution offered by Md. Abu Taher: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46948489/puppeteer-wait-page-load-after-form-submit) but this is way more elegant imo.

Comment: Can confirm what Icrespilho says, adding the `waitForFunction` after adding the scriptTag does nothing. I think the problem is OP thinking that `addScriptTag` is executed automatically for new pages.

Comment: I added it as a "confirmation", some site might overwrite jQuery. However, the discussion looks really interesting. I will go over it and update accordingly. Thank you everyone. :)

Answer (score 0):

For typescript, window.JQuery gives me error, so I solved it with

```
page.waitForFunction(() => window.$);
```