# How can I get Puppeteer to take PDF of new page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, puppeteer, headless

I am messing with Puppeteer and I am having trouble getting it to take a PDF of a new page.

I can get a PDF of the initial URL just fine, but if I try to get a PDF of a page I open via clicking on a link, it just takes a PDF of the initial page like always.

This is my code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function takePDF(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
       slowMo:500, defaultViewport:null
    });
    
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    startUrl = 'https://www.google.com/';

    await page.goto(startUrl);

    await page.mouse.click(1030,468, { button: 'left'});    //click I'm Feeling Lucky

    await page.pdf({path: 'screenshot.pdf'});   //take pdf of I'm Feeling Lucky Results

    browser.close();
}

takePDF();
```

Do I have to fetch the URL and explicitly tell it it's on a new page now? Thanks.

Comment: try adding some wait time after the click. You might just be taking a screenshot before the page redirects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Puppeteer wait page load after form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46948489/puppeteer-wait-page-load-after-form-submit)

Comment: Try a waitFor before page.pdf it could be help you.