# Trying to automate reporting process on a website by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to automate submissions of [TikTok copyright infringement reports](https://www.tiktok.com/legal/report/Copyright) with JavaScript. I have tried this code so far:

```
document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value = 'Name Here'
```

When I attempt to submit the form, the site clears the textbox and asks me to fill out this required field. Any clue what I am doing wrong? I have also tried this:

```
document.getElementsByName('name')[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
```

Comment: Hey! That question is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually
And there's also an answer which may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2856602/3137698

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing exactly how that React form handles the input, it's hard to know what event needs triggering.

You can use [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) to do this much easier, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45778181/puppeteer-how-to-submit-a-form) for examples